# Specialised constructor for Vector class

Tags: c++, templates, math, vectormath

I'm trying to write a math vector class. A first version goes like :

```
  template <typename T, unsigned int n>
    struct Vector {
    Vector<T, n>(T t = T()) // default
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            data[i] = t;
        }
    }

    Vector<T, n>(const Vector<T, n> &aVector)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            data[i] = aVector.data[i];
        }
    }

    Vector<T, n>(const T arr[n])
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            data[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    T& operator[](unsigned int i);
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const;
    Vector<T, n>& operator=(const Vector<T, n> &aVector);

    void normalise();   

    T data[n]; 
    };
```

I also have operators (+, *, etc.) declared outside the class, as well as a couple of other classes.

Here's the thing though. For vectors of length 2, 3, 4 I'd like to have a constructor (or a function) that takes x,y (for Vec2), x,y,z or  x,y,z,w as parameters.

However, it seems that you can't make specialised constructors for this purpose. How should I proceed in that case ? Do I have to completely specialise three cases ? Wouldn't that imply that I have to rewrite chunks of code ?

I also have a similar Matrix class ( Matrix), and I'm pretty sure I'll need some constructors for rotation, translation, scaling, etc. I'm assuming I'll need to overcome a similar problem.

If you see

I also have operators (+, *, etc.) declared outside the class, as well as a couple of other functions (dot, cross, etc.).

Here's the thing though. For vectors of length 2, 3, 4 I'd like to have a constructor (or a function) that takes x,y (for Vec2), x,y,z or  x,y,z,w as parameters.

However, it seems that you can't make specialised constructors for this purpose. How should I proceed in that case ? Do I have to completely specialise three cases ? Wouldn't that imply that I have to rewrite chunks of code ?

I also have a similar Matrix class ( Matrix), and I'm pretty sure I'll need some constructors for rotation, translation, scaling, etc. I'm assuming I'll need to overcome a similar problem.

If you see anything in the code that seems wrong to you, feel free to point it out by the way.

EDIT : In case I was not clear enough, the arrays are meant to be one-dimensional, and all of its components are of the same type. The specialisations are for arrays with 2, 3 and 4 elements.

Comment: On a side note -- your `Vector` class does not need a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: `For vectors of length 2, 3, 4`  Do you mean the number of *dimensions* can be 2, 3, or 4?

Comment: Arrays within structs are copyable without further assistance.  Thus a user-defined copy constructor / assignment op is not needed.

Comment: Why not just send a `std::vector` (not the same as your `Vector`) of values, where the `vector::size()` determines if you have 2, 3, 4, or `n` items?

Comment: Because I don't want to be checking for size everytime I do something to my vectors or matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may utilize a variadic template:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>


template<typename T, unsigned int n>
struct Vector
{
    // Note: We need x and y:
    // The default (in the question) is a constructor taking a single argument.
    template <typename ... Args>
    Vector(T x, T y, Args ... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof ... (Args) == n - 2, "Invalid number of arguments");
        auto initializer_list = { x, y, std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        std::copy(initializer_list.begin(), initializer_list.end(), data);

    }

    T data[n];
};


template<typename T, unsigned int n>
void print(const Vector<T, n>& v) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << v.data[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    Vector<int, 2> v2(1, 2);
    Vector<int, 3> v3(1, 2, 3);
    Vector<int, 4> v4(1, 2, 3, 4);
    print(v2);
    print(v3);
    print(v4);

    // Invalid number of arguments
    // Vector<int, 3> e2(1, 2);

    // Invalid number of arguments
    // Vector<int, 3> e4(1, 2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would declare different classes for each vector. `Vec2<T1, T2>`, `Vec3<T1, T2, T3>`, and `Vec4<T1, T2, T3, T4>`. Make each `Vec*` class publicly inherit a un-templated base class `Vector`, and then make a static function `create` in `Vector` with an overload for each `Vec*` type that will be responsible for creating them. Pseudo-example for `Vec3`:

```
template<T1, T2, T3> static std::shared_ptr<Vector> create(T1 a1, T2 a2, T3 a3)
{
    return new Vec3<T1, T2, T3>(a1, a2, a3);
}
auto vec = Vector::create<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

variadic template and SFINAE may solve that.
but I think the simpler would be to inherit from (specialized) helper

```
template <typename T, unsigned int n>
struct VectorHelper<T, n>
{
    T data[n];
};

template <typename T>
struct VectorHelper<T, 2>
{
    VectorHelper(T x, T y) : {data[0] = x; data[1] = y;}
    T data[2];
};

template <typename T>
struct VectorHelper<T, 3>
{
    VectorHelper(T x, T y, T z) : {data[0] = x; data[1] = y; data[2] = z}
    T data[3];
};


template <typename T, unsigned int n>
struct Vector : private VectorHelper<T, n>
{
    using VectorHelper<T, n>::VectorHelper; // use base constructor(s)
    // your previous implementation without `data` (as member of base)
};
```